Create a view in postgres conditionally
I have a schema where there are associated tables. It can be one of the 2 states.
State 1:



Table A
Table B
Table C




col 1
col 4
col 6


col 2
col 5
col 7


col 3





State 2:



Table A
Table B
Table C




col 1
col 1
col 5


col 2
col 4
col 6


col 3
col 5



col 4





I need to create a generic view definition where I need to select col 4 from table A if column exist on table A OR do a join to table B and select the column 4 if table A does not have column 4.
I can use schema info to know if the column exist on the table, but I am not sure how to use that in a query conditionally.
Any help is appreciated.

The question is unclear, but I don't think a view can be the solution. Why do you want that view? This sounds like a task for procedural programming, for example in a database function.

The tables are in diff schema and the view is in another schema, we need to get a consolidated view (Model) so middle layer can query. But we are not sure which stage the tables are in either state 1 or state 2. We only have control of the view as we are working on that schema.

I would like to avoid joining second table if the column is already available in the first table as the tables has lot of data (millions of record).

A view doesn't make the query any simpler (to execute). If you write a view, you will still join the tables. Views are replaced by their definition during query planning.
